# How do I start the Temple of Miraak quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

I've recently added the Dragonborn DLC to my Skyrim (PS3). I setup a new character and went to Solstheim.

After doing a number of quests and discovering pretty much ever location on Solstheim I seem to have stalled on the main story line.

When I visit the Temple of Miraak I don't see/meet Frea.

I've read elsewhere that if I travelled back to Skyrim some cultists would attack me, which would trigger the question. But I've spent about 8 hours back on Skyrim doing various quests - and still nothing has happened.

Has anyone else come across this issue and know how to trigger the Temple of Miraak quest?

I've got a good level 38 character who's built around stealth kills with the Bound Bow, and I'd hate to have to start again.

Comment: Chances are that you are to low of a level to continue. I played this DLC with a level 74 character with no stops no matter how much I went of the main story line. Through out the whole game of Skyrim there is level caps for quests some people are just lucky to never get them because they are always ahead of the cap.

Comment: Heh, I managed to walk into the temple a level 7 sneak/restoration Dunmer. Big mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The prerequisite quest for **[The Temple of Miraak](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Temple_of_Miraak)** is **[Dragonborn](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dragonborn_%28Quest%29)**, which as you correctly suggest is triggered by reading the orders of the two random(ish) encounter Cultists who attack you in Skyrim.  However, the prerequisite for the Dragonborn quest is not level related but requires your character to have started **[The Horn of Jurgen Windcaller](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Horn_of_Jurgen_Windcaller_%28Quest%29)** for the Greybeards in order to be triggered.

If you visited Solstheim before starting The Horn of Jurgen Windcaller (*even if you then later started and completed it*) then UESP suggests that you must return to Windhelm and talk to the ship captain, Gjalund Salt-Sage, again to proceed in the quest.

Comment: Thank you @Rory - you are totally right. After finishing "Way of the Voice" and starting "The Horn of Jurgen Windcaller" I was immediately set upon by two cultists in Ivaarstead.